# changing an array to an Object (upper case) by adding a value using a dot

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Does adding a property to an array with dot notation change it to an object?

```
var arr = [];

arr.something = "test";
```

is it an array?

I don't think so, but underscore.js says it is

```
console.log( _.isArray(arr) );  //true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wZcyG/

Comment: Here is the code that you are working with: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-112

Comment: My guess is once you evaluate this line 'arr = []' `arr`'s type is set. After that there isn't an opportunity for the VM to know that the type has changed until the next assignment.

Comment: @Adi Inbar That title was purposeful. Why did you editit? Isn't that the correct way to specify it?

Comment: A JavaScript `Array` **is** an `Object`. What's the issue?

Comment: @idbehold I don't understand how your comment, while true, relates to the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @thomas you asked if adding a property to an array would change it into an object, but the array is/was always an object. So it didn't change. It's like asking, "If I put a toilet in my kitchen would it change into a room?" …It was always a room. It's just a weird room now since a toilet is not something you'd normally put in a kitchen.

Comment: @thomas Well, I tried to roll back the edit when I saw you object, but my rollback edit was rejected. Admittedly I'm not a javascript expert by a long shot, but as far as I can tell you're asking about changing an array into an object, not into an Object object. Conceptually that doesn't even make sense to me. Object objects provide prototypical functionality to other objects, so what does it even mean to change an array into an Object object by adding a property? That's probably why my rollback request was rejected, because the way you had it originally didn't make sense...can you explain?

Comment: @AdiInbar It was a way to specify I was talking about object `{}`, not function or array. Just the way it looks when you call its `toString()` method. No worries.

Comment: @idbehold I think you saw my question after someone edited the title. It was originally changing to object Object. Like, `{}`, that sort of object. Not sure what to call that sort of `key: value` object, but I didn't change the edit, because I thought the editor might know more than I. Even though I agree, written like it is now, it does seem sort of nonsensical. Of course an array is an object. I didn't consider that you may have only seen that edit when you posted your comment.

Comment: @thomas Okay. As I said, my edit to roll back the original edit wasn't accepted, but I believe that as the author you can edit it back, since self-edits aren't subject to peer review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the underscore.js [source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), you will see that the `isArray` function is defined as:

```
 _.isArray = nativeIsArray || function(obj) {
    return toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
  };
```

The brower's native `Array.isArray` says it's an array because that's what it has been instantiated as. If the browser doesn't have a native `isArray`, then underscore.js uses the second option: comparing `toString` on the object to see if it matches the string `[object Array]`.

Simply adding a property is not enough to change the *type* of the object (according to the JavaScript virtual machine, it is still an object that happens to be an array). JavaScript is a dynamic language which means that you can add properties to in-built objects, but doing so does not change what they are; you have merely extended them. For example, Prototype.js used to extend native objects by adding extra properties to them (like iterators, filters, mapping functions, etc.).

You can see the behavior in Chrome pretty easily:

```
> var arr = [];
  arr.something = "test";

> Array.isArray(arr);
  true

> toString.call(arr);
  "[object Array]"
```

**EDIT**

The array doesn't lose its `length` property:

```
> var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  arr.something = "test";
  console.log(arr.length, arr.something);

  3 "test"
```

Notice that the browser reported the correct length of `3` and the correct value for `test` for the `something` property.

Comment: But it loses its `length` method? So it is changed on some fundamental level, no?

Comment: paste the above code in your console. FF says it has both length = 0 and .something = test

Comment: which length method? length is also a property

Comment: @thomas No, it doesn't lose its `length` property. Check out my edit.

Comment: No, That's what my "Too true" was about. I got it now!