# A few questions on where properties are stored in Objects

Tags: javascript

[I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845488/changing-an-array-to-an-object-by-adding-a-value-using-a-dot) why backbone.js's `_.isArray(arr)` function still returns true, even if I do something like,

```
var a = [];
    a.something = "test";
```

Because I sort of expected it to be turned into an `[object Object]` (not sure if that is the correct way to reference the object that gets made when you do `var o = {}`, but I'm talking about the type of object you can use key: value pairs with. Any insight on how to refer to that object, is much welcome.

I received the answer that it is not changing what the data type of `a` is, merely adding the property `something` to it. I can see in the console that I get a.something = "test", but where is this stored? Is it in the array's prototype? (I'm pretty sure not). But what does it mean simply "add a property"?

```
var a = "";
a.asdf = "test";
a.zxcv = "test1";
```

won't return the property similarly because the string isn't an object, but a function should be an object, yet

```
var a = function(){};

    a.asdf = "test";
    a.zxcv = "test1";

    console.log(a);
```

only returns

```
function (){

}
```

(It kind of looks like a string...) I don't know why I wouldn't be able to do `var a = new Function()` (even though I've never seen it before); it returns the same as directly above. Also jslint says it's eval. Why..?

I'm just trying to figure out what is meant by "adding properties to objects" and where these properties "go", and why they act differently in different types of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are several primitive types, including `undefined`, `number`, and `string`. There are also `object`s. All objects have properties.

Every lowercase-o object was created from a constructor. In the case of object literal notation, the constructor was an implicit `Object`. Arrays are objects too, but rather than being created with the `Object` constructor, they're created with the `Array` constructor. Functions are objects too, which have the `Function` constructor.

### Arrays

When you see an array, you likely think of it as having numbered elements; 0, 1, 2, etc. In reality, an array is just another object, except that rather than using alphabetic property names, it uses numeric property names, and you don't use `.` to access the elements.

In reality, arrays have some optimizations by browsers to make them faster than if you were using a different kind of object, but such optimizations will still retain the semantics described here.

### Boxing

The odd behavior with strings is because strings aren't objects, but there's some quirky boxing behavior that makes `someString.property = value` not an error. Only objects can have properties and methods per se; but we all know that `someNumber.toString()` is not an error. What's up there?

It turns out that in some cases, when you try to use a primitive as if it were an object, it will box up that primitive into an object. For example, when I call `someNumber.toString()`, it will create an object with the `Number` constructor, distinct from the primitive number. Then it looks up `toString` in the normal way, executing it with `this` set to the object.

When you set the property on the string, it was implicitly converted to a `String`-constructor object for the purposes of that operation. It set the property on the `String` object just fine; it's just that the boxing was temporary; the boxing does not persist in the variable holding the primitive string.

### Function objects

It's true that we rarely use `new Function`, but if you do use it, it does exactly what it sounds like it does: it creates a new function. You can pass it a string, and that will be the body of the function. If you create a new function with a string body and then call it, that's not too far from `eval`ing code. That's why JSLint marks it as an `eval`.

When you log an object to the console, developer tools will usually show you the properties since that's usually the most important part of the object. Functions usually aren't assigned custom properties, so developer tools just go with the plain string representation, which usually just shows the function arguments and body. The string representation of a function isn't that unusual in not showing properties — `toString` of a plain `Object` will just return `[object Object]`.

### The prototype chain

Surely this information clarifies many things, but it still doesn't explain this:

```
console.log(new Array() instanceof Object);  // => true
```

Wha? The constructor of the array is `Array`, not `Object`! This is because of something called the prototype chain. It is what controls inheritance.

Every object has an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. There is no standard way to access it, although many browsers have a non-standard `__proto__` property to access it. When you use `new` to create an object, `[[Prototype]]` is set to the `prototype` property of the function used to create the object.

Let's say we have an object `foo` that had a constructor of `Foo`. When we access a property `foo.bar`, it first looks up `bar` in `foo`'s own properties. If it's not found there or undefined, it will look up `bar` in `foo`'s `[[Prototype]]`'s own properties. If not found there, it will look up `bar` in `foo`'s `[[Prototype]]`'s `[[Prototype]]`, on and on, until it gets to a `null` `[[Prototype]]`. This is the functionality that allows inheritance.

In order to determine whether an object is an instance, `isinstance` goes through the prototype chain to see if any of the `[[Prototype]]`s match the `prototype` of the function. It just turns out that if you traverse the prototype chain of an array, you'll hit `Array`'s prototype, `Object`'s prototype, and then `null`. Therefore, `isinstance` will yield `true` in `new Array() instanceof Object`.

### Further reading

You may be interested in the [annotated ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.io/), which defines the language, and of course covers some of the specific algorithms used in detail. It won't lay everything out for you; some very insightful things are not explicitly described, but require piecing several bits together on your own. For that reason, you probably don't want to read it straight through unless you're trying to implement it yourself, but rather reference sections of it whenever there's some behavior you're curious about.

Comment: Hmm. So that's why `var arr = [];

arr.test1 = "res1";
arr.test2 = "res2";
arr.test3 = "res3";

for (var i in arr){
 console.log(arr[i]);   
}` works just like looping through an object Object (btw, you simply call it "uppercase object"?) So every object (lowercase and uppercase) has the ability to store properties like this? But why can't I add properties to the `new Function` instantiation with the dot?

Comment: @thomas: I wanted to distinguish between objects in general (lowercase o; this includes objects like `Array`s) and the uppercase-o `Object` constructor. As for functions, you can and did add a property successfully; it's just that the string representation doesn't show it. If you try to access it after setting it, you'll find that it's still there.

Comment: Tomorrow? Because you've just piqued my curiosity with the word "chain".... Bed time now though!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, array is just an object with preassigned keys from 0 to n number of values that you provide.

`var x = ['a','b','c','d',234];` is exactly like

`var x = {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:234,length:5};`  and all array functions will work on it with array calls like this `Array.prototype.sort.push(x,'sdfsd');`.

All methods/properties of Main Object are inherited by all arrays.

so when you assign a non numeric value to an array, lets say with 2 elements. It gets added like this...

```
var x =['a','Stack','flow',0];
--added value x.a = 'something';
it really looks like this now
var x = {
    0:'a',
    1:'Stack',
    2:'flow',
    3:'0',
    a:'something'
    }
```

however, to js **x** is still an array, and when you just run any function on **x**, **a** wont show up. Until you access it like `x.a`.

```
x.hasOwnProperty('a'); //true

Object.keys(x); //listing all keys in object(array x)
// ["0", "1", "2", "3", "a"] !!!keys function returns an array consisting of all keys in an object.
```

**Function Objects** are Different they aren't just Objects with keys.

You can still assign stuff to them but they will return function only. You can access properties like x.a etc. But dont do it.

**Summary**

Everything inherits from `Object` object and therefore can have properties and methods.

Arrays are specialized objects, called `Array` which inherit methods/props from `Object`, that store values in indexed keys named 0-n form. But again can have extra properties and methods due to inheritance, although the  wont show up in array methods or properties.

Functions are Objects which inherits from `function object` which inherits from `Object` so functions(functionObjects) have properties from both. Functions have extra properties too like prototype and arguments.

When you write this:...

`var x = new function anonymous/named (){}`
**3 things happen:**
 1. x = {};
 2. function executes...if it has this.p = etcc...then x gets it and x become x= {p:'etc'}
 3. x.**proto** = function.prototype

then if you look up a property or method in x and is not found there js will look if there is something in proto then which refers to function's prototype object it goes there and search there. That's how you have classes in Javascript.

Comment: `var x = {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:234};

x.push("test");

console.loc(x);` throws a typeError. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: even though `var arr = new Function();

arr.test1 = "res1";
arr.test2 = new Function();
arr.test3 = {};

for (var i in arr){
 console.log(typeof arr[i]);   
}` does work like you say. I'm still not having any luck using array methods on objects, as you say is possible.

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort.push(x,'sdfsd');` lmao i should have mentioned since not all objects inherit array method and arrays do. So you have to call them like that. And they will work.